# Merging two data tables by code but recognize where it was scanned first

Tags: r, powerbi, posixct

I'm working on some data which contains rejected and accepted data. These are separated in two separated log files. I want to merge them with R-code.

But if a code was rejected it *could* be accepted later on. And the other way around. If you used the code already it should be rejected later on.

I want to make a merge between these two tables cause when you're code is rejected I also get a code why it was rejected in the first place when someone used the code at the wrong day or at the wrong store and uses it later on at the right place and time I can find it back in the accepted log file.

my code looks like this:

```
head(ACCEPTED)
                                   
code   Overruled device      date
1 29    FALSE   05       2017-02-23 16:27:56
2 30    FALSE   05       2017-02-23 16:27:58
3 09    FALSE   05       2017-02-23 16:28:31
4 06    FALSE   08       2017-02-23 16:28:34
5 27    FALSE   08       2017-02-23 16:28:39
6 07    FALSE   08       2017-02-23 16:28:59

head(REJECTED)
code   CODE device         date
1 29    1   01        2017-02-22 12:47:49
2 07    5   01        2017-02-23 16:48:25
3 00    2   01        2017-02-23 12:50:00
4 09    3   01        2017-02-23 16:51:23
5 87    1   07        2017-02-23 16:25:29
6 98    1   03        2017-02-23 16:25:47
```

I already merged them by barcode but then I didn't include the fact that I wanted to know the origin where the code was first used.

- So for code 29 it was first rejected on the 22 and accepted on the 23.
- But code 09 was first accepted and then rejected (someone tried to use the code later on, but failed because it was already used)

Some code is not in both tables because it either was accepted or rejected and not used again.

I want a table that can work with chord  visualisation tool from Microsoft power BI
[image: chord, power BI]

the new data frame should look like this:

```
 code   from   to
 29     01     05 # because the code was first seen at 01 and then scanned at 05
 09     05     01 
 07     08     01
```

If the code doesn't exist in the other table it should not appear in the new table. Normal merging works by code but it should be in order of appearance of the code.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As much as I don't like non-answers, why does it have to be done in R? What is your data source? It might be better to join them before importing.

Comment: it comes from a program that only gives log files. If you want to connect directly it gets overloaded and the oparational process is crucial. so that's not an option.

Comment: I see. And is `code` column unique within each table?

Comment: no because somethimes it gets scanned more than once (only in rejected)

Comment: You may need to remove duplicates, or explain how exactly it should work in that scenario. (For example if `rejected_date_1 < accepted_date < rejected_date_2`) I posted an answer with a general solution which worked with the sample data you provided.

Comment: Yes that's the difficulty that I have to think about but you're answer works indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join tables by means of Power Query:

- Edit Queries
- Right Click under `Queries` -> `New Query` -> `Combine` -> `Megre Queries as New`
- select the two tables and then `code` column under each.
- specify `Join Kind`.
- expand `NewColumn`

---

Once you join the two tables:

```
code   Overruled device.ac   date.ac          CODE.rej  device.rej     date.rej
29      FALSE       05    2017-02-23 16:27:56   1          01   2017-02-22 12:47:49
09      FALSE       05    2017-02-23 16:28:31   3          01   2017-02-23 16:51:23
07      FALSE       08    2017-02-23 16:28:59   5          01   2017-02-23 16:48:25
```

You can then add calculated columns:

```
from = IF(new[date.ac]<new[date.rej],new[device.ac],new[device.rej])
to = IF(new[date.ac]>new[date.rej],new[device.ac],new[device.rej])
```

Results in:

```
code from to
7    8    1
9    5    1
29   1    5
```